# Should I validation in WEB.UI Models folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have done custommembership as this link: 
http://www.brianlegg.com/post/2011/05/09/Implementing-your-own-RoleProvider-and-MembershipProvider-in-MVC-3.aspx

My soulution have two project : CameraStore.Domain and CameraStore.WebUI. In CameraStore.Domain porject, i have an entity named User like this:

```
public int UserID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Ward")]
    public string Ward { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [Display(Name = "Phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Order { get; set; }
```

In my Register Controller method i want to insert user into my database. But i have the field ConfirmPassword, how can i valid it if this property never has in User Entity class. I have used a class named AccountUserModels to return 2 List for 2 dropdownlist in my view, can i add the property ConfirmPassword to this class. I dont want to valid by javascript for ConfirmPassword filed in my view.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if i not wrong you want to compare password right?

try this

```
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "New password is required.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 5)]
        [Display(Name = "New password:")]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirm password is required.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 5)]
        [Compare("NewPassword")]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password:")]
        public string RePassword { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }


    return RedirectToAction("Success");
}
```